# Why is SynchronizedCollection<T> in the System.ServiceModel assembly?

Tags: .net

I was wondering if anybody has any idea why the SynchronizedCollection<T> class was implemented in the ServiceModel assembly. I cannot see any connection between the assembly name and this (relatively) general purpose class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is quite specific, and its name could even be misleading - its internal implementation does virtually nothing except for wrapping *some* operations (`Insert`, `Add`, `Clear`, `IndexOf` etc.) in `lock (this.sync) {}` block, which doesn't make it actually *Synchronized* (see concerns described in [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20120526014618/https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36079/System-Collections-Generic-SynchronizedCollection) - in short, compound operations like LINQ `FirstOrDefault` are not thread-safe on `SynchronizedCollection`, as they do not acquire the lock).

It is heavily used in `ServiceModel` assembly itself, and probably was made `public` only because some `ServiceModel` classes expose public properties of this type.

So my guess is: it was put into `ServiceModel` assembly because it doesn't really belong to BCL and is just a DRYish BCL namespace extension for internal `ServiceModel` needs.

Comment: Got here through the following error:  "the type or namespace name 'synchronizedcollection' could not be found".  This makes sense, but Microsoft's documentation appears to be flawed, because it said it was in System.Collections.Generic

Comment: Updated the link and added short example of an issue.